# How to remove indentation space from multiple lines with visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

Evening, i tried to find some way to remove spaces from code written in multiple lines in visual studio but i wasn't able to, though, i found a way to make the inverse of what i want to do, say that i have this code in visualstudio:

```
const a = 1
const b = 2
const c = 3
```

and then i copy and paste some code from another place in this file like this:

```
const a = 1
const b = 2
const c = 3
    const d = 4
    const e = 5
    const f = 6
```

as you can see, what i pasted doesn't have the same indentation spaces as the code i had before, something i can do to make it have the same indentation spaces is highlight what i had previously and hit "tab" so the code ends looking like this:

```
    const a = 1
    const b = 2
    const c = 3
    const d = 4
    const e = 5
    const f = 6
```

But what i want to do is the opposite, to highlight the code that i pasted and remove the extra spaces so that it ends up looking like this:

```
const a = 1
const b = 2
const c = 3
const d = 4
const e = 5
const f = 6
```

is there a way to accomplish what i want to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

highlight all the lines that you want to unindent and press shift+tab

Answer (score 2):

Use **Alt+LeftClick** to create a vertical cursor at the beginning of the text and hit the *Backspace* key once.  You can use this to type text on multiple lines, delete text from multiple lines, and to create rectangular **Copy/Paste** selections.